# jQuery - Long text tooltip displayed incorrectly in modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal that contains first name, last name and email. I want to display a tooltip for long strings that don't fit in the modal, but it's not displayed correctly.

I tried with two options as shown above:

**First option: jQuery tooltip**

[image]

This is the HTML code that displays first name in the modal:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"> First Name </div>
{% if row[1]|length >100 %}
    <div class="col-sm-9" id = "firstname" title="{{row[1]}}"> {%print row[1]|truncate(80) %} </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="col-sm-9">{% print row[1]%}</div>
{% endif %}
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#firstname").tooltip();
 });
```

**Second option: Only title attribute**

Using only title attribute:

```
<div class="col-sm-9"title="{{row[1]}}"> {%print row[1]|truncate(80) %} </div>
```

This displays only part of the string:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this css

```
  .tooltip-inner {
                max-width: none!important;
                white-space: nowrap !important;
            }
```

working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vSTLU/2504/)

Answer (score 0):

> Try to take the extended message to next line. 1) Fix the tooltip width. 2)add the below css property for tooltip text:

```
word-break: break-all;
```